# Unindexed Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am looking for the command line command that will display the same thing as the gui

```
Unindexed Foreign Keys
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no command line command (that I know of) which does it. But you can roll your own. Basically you need a query which checks the database for these, which is effectively what your GUI tool must be doing. The query would be something like:

```
SELECT  FK.table_name, FK.constraint_name
FROM    user_constraints FK
WHERE   FK.constraint_type = 'R'
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  FC.position, FC.column_name
            FROM    user_cons_columns FC
            WHERE   FC.constraint_name = FK.constraint_name
            MINUS
            SELECT  IC.column_position AS position, IC.column_name
            FROM    user_ind_columns IC
            WHERE   IC.table_name = FK.table_name
        )
```

NOTE: This SQL is NOT perfect. There could be situations where it is fooled into thinking there is an index bet there's not really. Multiple different indexes with columns in the right place could fool it. To do it properly you'll need to start grouping in inline views or use analytic functions to ensure all the index columns come from the same index. So I left it at this simple version which will work most of the time.

Then you can run this SQL in sqlplus, or you could embed it in a shell script which is easily run from the command line. A crude one would be:

```
#!/bin/bash -ue

LOGIN="$1"
sqlplus -s << END_SQL
    $LOGIN
    SET PAGESIZE 5000
    SELECT  FK.table_name, FK.constraint_name
    FROM    user_constraints FK
    WHERE   FK.constraint_type = 'R'
    AND     EXISTS
            (   SELECT  FC.position, FC.column_name
                FROM    user_cons_columns FC
                WHERE   FC.constraint_name = FK.constraint_name
                MINUS
                SELECT  IC.column_position AS position, IC.column_name
                FROM    user_ind_columns IC
                WHERE   IC.table_name = FK.table_name
            )
/
END_SQL
```

Which you can then run like this and get the basic results:

```
[user@centos5 sql]$ ./fk.sh scott/tiger@orcl

TABLE_NAME                     CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
EMP                            FK_DEPTNO
```

Comment: This is one I will stick to the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a script which should work correctly every time, courtesy of Steve Adams:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Script:  missing_fk_indexes.sql
-- Purpose: to check for locking problems with missing foriegn key indexes
-- For:     8.1 and higher
--
-- Copyright:   (c) Ixora Pty Ltd
-- Author:  Steve Adams
--
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@save_sqlplus_settings

column constraint_name noprint
column table_name format a48
break on constraint_name skip 1 on table_name

select /*+ ordered */
  n.name  constraint_name,
  u.name ||'.'|| o.name  table_name,
  c.name  column_name
from
  (
    select /*+ ordered */ distinct
      cd.con#,
      cd.obj#
    from
      sys.cdef$  cd,
      sys.tab$  t
    where
      cd.type# = 4 and          -- foriegn key
      t.obj# = cd.robj# and
      bitand(t.flags, 6) = 0 and    -- table locks enabled
      not exists (          -- not indexed
    select
      null
    from
      sys.ccol$  cc,
          sys.ind$  i,
      sys.icol$  ic
    where
          cc.con# = cd.con# and
          i.bo# = cc.obj# and
          bitand(i.flags, 1049) = 0 and     -- index must be valid
          ic.obj# = i.obj# and
      ic.intcol# = cc.intcol#
        group by
          i.obj#
        having
          sum(ic.pos#) = (cd.cols * cd.cols + cd.cols)/2
      )
  )  fk,
  sys.obj$  o,
  sys.user$  u,
  sys.ccol$  cc,
  sys.col$  c,
  sys.con$  n
where
  o.obj# = fk.obj# and
  o.owner# != 0 and         -- ignore SYS
  u.user# = o.owner# and
  cc.con# = fk.con# and
  c.obj# = cc.obj# and
  c.intcol# = cc.intcol# and
  n.con# = fk.con#
order by
  2, 1, 3
/

@restore_sqlplus_settings
```

Hope that helps.